# How to make the event wait until a boolean is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an event registered.

```cs
layout.SizeChanged += parentToggleBox.Resize;
```

Problem is, I would like this Resize event to wait until my mouse has moved away from the box.

How to make this event wait until a boolean is changed from false to true?
or wait until `OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`  is triggered?

Comment: set a flag saying that the resize happened, then test that flag when that bool changes or when the onmouseleave triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that I put together:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Panel Panel1;
    private Label Label1;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Panel1 = new Panel()
        {
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red,
        };

        this.Label1 = new Label()
        {
            Top = 200,
            Text = "Click",
        };

        bool clicked = false;
        bool entered = false;

        this.Panel1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            clicked = true;
        };

        this.Panel1.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            clicked = false;
            entered = true;
        };

        this.Panel1.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (entered && clicked)
            {
                this.Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                this.Label1.Text = "Success";
            }
        };

        this.Controls.Add(this.Panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Label1);
    }
}
```

I've used a `Click` event rather than a `Resize` to demonstrate the technique.

Effectively this is just setting two booleans and when the right combination of `entered` and `clicked` occurs then the code in the block that contains `this.Label1.Text = "Success";` will run.

The colours are set for debugging purposes.

To run, do this:

```
var form1 = new Form1();
form1.ShowDialog();
```